# Ubuntu main directory

Tags: command-line, files, directory, cd, virtual-console

Good day
I want to make

```
/mnt/c/Users/joey/Desktop
```

as my default directoy so when I close then open my terminal it will be my main default directoy

thanks

Comment: yes iam using ubuntu in windows and iam using ubunutu app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `cd` command and the directory of your desire to the `.bashrc` file, you can edit it with vi, nano, or append the output of `echo` to that file, something like:

```
echo "cd /mnt/c/Users/joey/Desktop" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked